# Trying to make icon hidden in IE9 with compatability mode

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to make an icon invisible when it is clicked, my HTML looks like this:

```
<img id="imgTop" style="border-width:0px;" src="../Images/Common/button-print-icon.gif" onclick="clicked()">
```

and the Javascript looks like this:

```
function clicked()
{
    document.getElementById("imgTop").hidden="";
    .....
}
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE 9 with compatibility mode it doesn't. I tried using several other methods (Such as passing `this` and using CSS style `display`), but nothing seems to work, can anyone help?

Comment: CSS display:none; or visibility:hidden; will work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using "compatibility mode"?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Because my employer supports IE7+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to options `visibility:hidden;` or `display:none;`

**Display None** - [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wMMS8/)

```
function clicked() {
    document.getElementById("imgTop").style.display = "none";
}
```

**Visibility Hidden** - [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wMMS8/1/)

```
function clicked() {
    document.getElementById("imgTop").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

---

The difference between visibility hidden and display none:

> **visibility**: hidden hides the element, but it still takes up space in
>   the layout.
>
> **display**: none removes the element completely from the document. It
>   does not take up any space, even though the HTML for it is still in
>   the source code.

[Source](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqhidden.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off setting the `style.visibility` property to `"hidden"`, like so:

```
document.getElementById("imgTop").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/4hVXZ/)

You should note though that settings `visibility` to `"hidden"` will hide the element but still keep it in the document flow - which means it will still take up space (unless it has absolute positioning or floated etc.). If this is the desired effect then you are good to go, if you want to "collapse" the element so other elements can shift into it's space then you can do the following instead:

```
document.getElementById("imgTop").style.display = "none";
```

[Here is another example](http://jsfiddle.net/4hVXZ/1/)